# What does read( ) (in C) return if there is nothing connected to the serial port?

Tags: c

I am using a serial port in my c program. If there is nothing connected to this serial port, what can I expect from a call of read( )in my program? Would the program hang or return an error?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the man page? `man 2 read` or http://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Comment: Even open() would fail, so you should not get to the stage op read()ing from the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) it would probably return **EBADF**.

Have you tried it? If not, it might be better to tell us what you want to achieve (block until something is connected, throw an error, etc.) so users can better guide you.